# SetFrom custom field

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want that in PHPMailer, the SetFrom is a filled in field.

```
$mail->setFrom('filled-in@field.com', 'Smaragd Express');
```

Does anyone know how I accomplish that?

Regards,
Joren

Answer (score 0):

To get a form field into your script is very simple. In your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="from">
```

When that's submitted it will turn up in your PHP script in the `$_POST` super global, and you can pass it to the `setFrom` method:

```
$mail->setFrom($_POST['name'], 'Smaragd Express');
```

**However**, you should *not* do this. Setting the From address to arbitrary values like this is forgery which will cause CPF checks to fail and your messages will either be rejected entirely or end up in spam folders. Instead, put your own address in the from address and the submitted address in a reply-to:

```
$mail->setFrom('me@example.com', 'Smaragd Express');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['name'], 'Smaragd Express');
```